# Scala macro annotations do not get expanded (macro paradise)

Tags: scala, compilation, macros, annotations, sbt

I'm trying to include macro annotations in my project. Following the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html), I tried implementing their example.

I am aware that the macro module has to be compiled before the core module (core being the module that contains the code that utilises the macro annotations). To achieve this I created the following build.sbt (version 1.2.8):

```
name := "test"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
)

lazy val macros = (project in file("macros")).settings(
  commonSettings,
  libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
)

lazy val core = (project in file("core")).settings(
  commonSettings
) dependsOn macros
```

The structure of my project is the following:

```
+-- .idea
+-- core
|   +-- src
|   |   +-- java
|   |   +-- scala
|   |   |   +-- Test.scala
+-- macros
|   +-- src
|   |   +-- java
|   |   +-- scala
|   |   |   +-- identity.scala
...
```

However, when I use the `@identity` annotation in the Test class, I still get the message that the macro annotation is not expanded (due to the `@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")`). Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

to `commonSettings` (Scala 2.11-2.12).

In Scala 2.13 it's enough to switch on `scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations"`

[Auto-Generate Companion Object for Case Class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74497076/auto-generate-companion-object-for-case-class-in-scala)

Comment: Thank you that was it! No more compilation error as of right now but the println of the macro described in the documentation still doesn't get executed.